# including Kal.a (from Kal calendar) and including libidn.a (xmpp framework) causes app to crash

Tags: iphone, ios5, xmpp, static-libraries

After trying really hard i am posting this qustion in the 2 o clock of night in my office.

The problem is :

1) i have included Kal calender ([link here](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal)) in my application

2) And its really working fine before i decided to include xmpp framework([xmpp framework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_Mac)) in my application.

3) The Main problem is when i try to include libidn.a file and then compile the project it gives me 4 errors , and to remove these error i have to remove "Other linker flag -> -all_load".

4) Here the problem begins when i have removed -all_laod flag and compile , app compiles success fully. But i try to run my app and press calendar button to load calender it crashes with following error:

> -[__NSDate cc_dateByMovingToFirstDayOfTheMonth]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75b85c0 2012-06-12 01:38:47.483 BizPro[10251:11903]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate
>   cc_dateByMovingToFirstDayOfTheMonth]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x75b85c0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x209e022 0x22f0cd6 0x209fcbd 0x2004ed0 0x2004cb2 0x12bc3d 0x12bb91 0x13149e 0x1315f6 0x12961 0xa8d38f
>   0xa8d5eb 0xa9dff1 0xa9e85f 0xa9e9e1 0xbbc5c2 0xa02d21 0x209fe42
>   0x856679 0x860579 0x7e54f7 0x7e73f6 0x874160 0x9d4f30 0x207299e
>   0x2009640 0x1fd54c6 0x1fd4d84 0x1fd4c9b 0x26e67d8 0x26e688a 0x9c4626
>   0x2a9d 0x2a15 0x1) terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

4) I know very well that this error is a misguide (NSDate is not causing the crash but the collision of static libraries is doing it , i think so) , because when i again add -all_load flag and remove the libidn.a file from my project , It compile and RUN successfully and calendar displays my data smoothly.

i googled a lot about it .. and got very little guidance .. relating the solution to workspaces and all that .. But i really dont know what could be the solution .. Plz help me

Thanks

Comment: `unrecognized selector sent to instance` means you try to access a selector which is not available or doesnt exist. check your propertys and synthesizes. to your point 3.) check your headers and try to solve the errors and not delete it.

Comment: I hope you figured it out, at least you helped me solve my problem! The all_load flag wasn't set for release.. So now a crashing app is in the app store -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry i am answering late ..

i solved the problem ..

removed kal.a file and just included src folder (all the header files required)

so that i will not collide with  the other static library ...

Answer (score 1):

```
cc_dateByMovingToFirstDayOfTheMonth
```

is an addition to NSDate that is defined in NSDateAdditions.h from the Kal Framework.

I had no end of problems and wanted more customisation of the Kal framework so I just dragged all the source code into my project.

If you still have issues with the framework then remove Kal.a and just bring in the source code :) then you can get dirty with it

Answer (score 1):

If you rather keep Kal as a subproject, the way to fix this is to link the addition files.

Under

Project -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags

add '-all_load'

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem here. Because I'm using Parse Framework, can't add `-all_load`, so integrating static library will never work for me. The simplest way is to add all source files in **src** folder to my own project, rather than adding **Kal.xcodeproj**. Other steps to config "copy bundle files" or "header search path" etc are still necessary. I also need to add these lines from Kal_Prefix.pch to my own project.pch.

```
#import "NSDate+Convenience.h"

#define RGBCOLOR(R,G,B) [UIColor colorWithRed:R/255.0 green:G/255.0 blue:B/255.0 alpha:1]
#define RGBACOLOR(R,G,B,A) [UIColor colorWithRed:R/255.0 green:G/255.0 blue:B/255.0 alpha:A]
#define kDarkGrayColor       RGBCOLOR(51, 51, 51)
#define kGrayColor           RGBCOLOR(153, 153, 153)
#define kLightGrayColor      RGBCOLOR(185, 185, 185)
```